# Scanner doesn't recognize a number on the first try?

Tags: java

If I input `1` or `3`, my game will start on the first try but if I input `2`, I'll get `invalid input. Try again :`. When I input 2 again, my game will start.

```
public static void Difficulty() {

            System.out.println("*********************************");
            System.out.println("* Welcome to Crypto's MathGame! *");
            System.out.println("*********************************");
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("[1] Easy Difficulty");
            System.out.println("[2] Medium Difficulty");
            System.out.println("[3] Hard Difficulty");
            System.out.print("Please choose an option : ");
            String option = input.nextLine();


            if((!("1".equals(option) || !("2".equals(option) || !("3".equals(option)))))){
                System.out.print("Invalid input. Try again : ");
                option = input.nextLine();
            }
        }
    }
```

**Why does my Scanner not recognize `'2'` on the first try?**

Comment: Because your `if` condition logically says **nothing** is valid. "2" is not "1" (or "3").

Comment: As a side note, you could consider using `input.nextInt()` and use numeric comparisons `if(option <= 0 || option > 3) { ... }`

Comment: Also, you brackets look wonky. Note what the first `!` is negating compared to the other `!`s.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch so what's the solution? I still don't understand why '1' and '3' get recognized right away but '2' needs to be inputted twice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
if(!("1".equals(option) || "2".equals(option) || "3".equals(option)))
{
    System.out.print("Invalid input. Try again : ");
    option = input.nextLine();
}
```

Comment: But more importantly @Crypto do you understand why your way *didn't* work?

Comment: Hmm. Not really. Is it because I had 3 !'s which made '2' reverse? could explain? :)

Comment: @Crypto It is because 1. you have used nested conditions 2. Wrong logic.
I would recommend you to draw the logic circuit (using logic gates) of your if statement and draw mine as well. Then you can easily find the difference.

Comment: @Crypto I suggest you read about [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws). `if (!"1".equals(option) && !"2".equals(option) && !"3".equals(option))`